# Cross-Platform Way of Creating Safari Webarchives

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, safari, webarchive

I've been searching around and haven't found any reference to tools that can create Safari's webarchive format.

Does anyone have pointers to code for creating this format, or at least a format reference documentation?

Ideally I'd like to build a tool that takes a directory and splits out a webarchive, for loading into a iPhone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on what Ben said: [CFLite](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/cflite.html) (the cross-platform open-source subset of Core Foundation) ships with a plist parser. If you can link against that, it should be quite simple to work with `.webarchive` files, which are simply property lists that concatenate all files (HTML, CSS, etc.) into one.

There are other libraries as well, such as [`Mac-PropertyList`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mac-PropertyList/) on CPAN for Perl.

Comment: Cross reference: [Reading .webarchive files in Unix-like environments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31602780/38108) (2015-07-24, work in progress)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the format for .webarchives is officially undocumented, but it's just a plist. You can open it in the Property List Editor and examine its contents. Shouldn't be to hard to replicate most, if not all, of what's in there.

Answer (score 3):

Tried textutil, but that only uses the Cocoa text system and as such fails at css, js and such.

There's a nice GitHub project: https://github.com/takebayashi/STWebArchiver

It uses Webkit to write .webarchive files. Needs some customization for your needs…

Answer (score 2):

It's not cross-plattform, but on the Mac

```
textutil -convert webarchive whatever.html
```

does the job. Not sure whether you can easily include images etc. though.

Comment: Use `man textutil` to see the documentation. There are quite a few options for webarchives.

Answer (score 1):

Webarchive creation is part of Webkit luckily, as such you can use the following for working with them on the Mac:

http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebArchive_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Or, use this sourcecode to understand the format in usage:

http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebArchive.mm

Comment: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKit/mac/WebView/WebArchive.mm is no longer found. http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7600.1.25/mac/WebView/ includes `WebArchive.h`, `WebArchive.mm` and `WebArchiveInternal.h` …