# How to create a .webarchive file on iPhone from a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

How do I create a .webarchive file from an embedded UIWebView?

Comment: If you wish to just cached (or download) the webpages, you can use ASIHttp (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which comes with ASIWebPageRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest)  to download complete webpages, including external resources like images and stylesheets. Pages of any size can be indefinitely cached, and displayed in a UIWebview even when you have no network connection.

Comment: Eventually I use this one: https://github.com/stake/STWebArchiver

Answer (score 0):

See also this question:

[Cross-platform webarchives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219530/cross-platform-way-of-creating-safari-webarchives)