# rtfd/.webarchive on *nix

Tags: webarchive

So I was tasked with converting rtfd files to tiffs.

First things first. We took the attachments that were in the folder (on a mac the "rtfd") and imaged those.

My issue lies in the splitting of the RTFD into multiple rtf files.
A co-worker suggested that the files be converted to html via a mac which we had limited access to. He converted the files in a day but the output was not a html like he had thought instead it was a .webarchive.

From what I have read, both of these formats are mac only formats. I refuse to accept that ...

The RTFD contains a file called TXT.rtf which is an rich text file but has undisplayable characters and strange formatting.

I can easily go into the rtf file and with a script split the file at the page breaks but then the strange formatting and undisplayable characters persist. When in the .webarchive format the files are inline to the text and thus cannot be rendered (at least as far as I can see)

At the moment I am at a loss, the only option I have not tried yet is taking the webarchives and printing them to PDF from safari.

Anyone have an experience with these files in a linux environment?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why one would want to convert searchable text into huge images. That aside, RTFD is a Mac format, so that's where you should work with it:

1. write a simple AppleScript to open files selected in the Finder in TextEdit and print them to PDF (the last part may require some UI scripting)
2. make an Automator workflow using the built-in "Render PDF Pages as Images"

Answer (score 0):

### Reading .webarchive files in Unix-like environments

[PC-BSD approaches to reading application/x-webarchive .webarchive (web archive) files](https://forums.pcbsd.org/thread-20082.html) (2015-07-21) – I'll cross reference this answer and if a solution is found, I'll post it here.

---

### Writing .webarchive files in Unix-like environments

As there was an accepted answer in 2008 to [Cross-Platform Way of Creating Safari Webarchives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/219530/38108), so I guess that there can/should be a way of reading the format in 2015 …