# how to read .webarchive file in android

Tags: android, git, webview, webarchive, warc

I have a requirement like this. I want to read .webarchive File. I have one file with .webarchive extension and i have put that file in asset folder. I want to read that file on android webview. Is it possible?

I googled and found some useful [link](https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader). This git content is really helpful.In this what it does is, put extracted content of .webarchive file in asset folder and from there data is shown on webview. My query is that i don't want to put extracted content in asset. I have file in .webarchive extension and want it to be opened directly in  webview.

i guees zipInputStream is just for file name with zip format extension,and another thing is that i read some where that only that zip files will be extracted with ZipInputStram which have been zipped with WinRar Software,Well in my case what i tried is I have tried to unizip webarchive file with follwing method http://pastie.org/8516247 and here is a log what i am getting

http://pastie.org/8516249,

now from this log you can see command is not even entering inside the while loop at line number 6 which is proved by this:

```
 log 11-29 13:01:46.903: V/Decompress(19936): 1
```

And if i am using any zip file inplace of test.warc at line number 4 than command is entering in while loop,that means this ZipInputStream is completely ignoring .WARC file,isn't it?

So if any one have idea how to extract .webarchive file or read .webarchive file without extracting it than please help me.

If any one having idea then please help me

Thanks

Comment: This this project having inbuilt https://github.com/gregko/WebArchiveReader and it is working fine and one more thing it also having an functionality to save webarchieve file of web so instead of using tha WARC file load your url in that project and save its webarchive file supported by the code and load it works like charm...

Comment: @Khan Thanks but this is not solution,please read my question properly,i already mention same link on my question

Comment: you want to read files which are archived, without extracting it?

Comment: @vinaykumar yes exactly,i am able to read it with extraction from that github code

Comment: @BinaryCode - have you tried ZipInputStream?

Comment: @vinaykumar i did not have idea about that ZipInputStream,Let me try and get back to you

Comment: I tried but it's not working,check my updated question

Comment: @Tombeau dead links

Answer (score 1):

### WebKit Bugzilla

#### [Bug 42716 – Implement WebArchive for Android](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42716)

That was [RESOLVED WONTFIX in 2012](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_activity.cgi?id=42716).

Still, what's there could be a good starting point, or point of continuation towards an acceptable answer to this question.

Comment: Side note: [Cross-Platform Way of Creating Safari Webarchives](http://stackoverflow.com/q/219530/38108) gained an accepted answer in 2008.